# Erro na chamada de ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Estou tento um erro de  **' Cannot read property 'razao_social' of undefined'** quando faço a chamada de uma ngModel no meu html.

Criei uma interface como esta:

```
export interface IEmpresas {
  nome_fantasia : string;
  razao_social : string;
  cnpj : string;
}
```

Em meu componente, eu instanciei a interface e criei uma variável com o tipo de minha interface.

```
...
private empresa : IEmpresas;
...
```

e então, eu chamo a ngModel no html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="empresa.razao_social" id="razao_social">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para iniciar o objeto com um valor vazio

```
private empresa : IEmpresas = {
  nome_fantasia : '';
  razao_social : '';
  cnpj : '';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A variavel empresa está iniciando como undefined, ou nulo.

Você declará-la com o operador safe ( empresa?.razao_social). Isso deve resolver, embora não seja a solução ideal.

Comment: compreendo. e neste caso qual seria a solução ideal?

Comment: A solução ideal pode depender de alguns fatores. Faz sentido que a variável empresa esteja vazia ? Isso seria uma falha na requisição ao backend ? Essa variável será carregada mais tarde quando a promise receber seu resultado ?

Essas questões influenciam um pouco. 

Mas você pode simplesmente inicializar essa variável com um objeto vazio no seu controller ou apenas utilizar o operador de navegação segura mesmo (?). O resultado será muito parecido e é sim uma boa solução, na minha opinião.